# Not receiving click event when clicking on custom buttons added beneath fancybox viewer?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using fancybox 2. I am trying to create a click event on the custom buttons I have added beneath the fancybox viewer:

[image]

I am concating each icon onto the title like so:

```
    $('.fancybox-photos').fancybox({
        type: 'image',
        beforeShow: function () {

            if (this.title) {
                // New line
                this.title += '<br />';

                // Add Facebook button
                var fullEncodedImageLink = encodeURI($(this.element).data("image-slug"));

                this.title += '<a class="fb-icon-link" target="blank" href=https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + fullEncodedImageLink +'><img class="social-icon-lightbox" src="mysite/third-party/images/custom-fb-icon.png"></a>';

                // Add google plus
                this.title += '<a href=https://plus.google.com/share?url=' + fullEncodedImageLink + ' onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, "", "menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600");return false;"><img class="social-icon-lightbox" src="mysite/third-party/images/custom-googleplus-icon.png" alt="Share on Google Plus"></a>';

                // Add twitter
                this.title += '<a href=http://www.twitter.com/share?url=' + fullEncodedImageLink + ' target="_blank"><img class="social-icon-lightbox" src="mysite/third-party/images/custom-twitter-icon.png" alt="Share on Twitter"></a>';

                // Add pinterest
                this.title += '<a data-pin-do="buttonBookmark" data-pin-custom="true" data-pin-save="false" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/"><img class="social-icon-lightbox" src="mysite/third-party/images/custom-pinterest-icon.png"/></a>';
            }
        }
    });
```

If I try and do the following, it is not reciving the click:

```
    $('.fb-icon-link').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Testing....');
    });
```

OR

```
    $('.social-icon-lightbox').on('click', function(){
        console.log('Testing....');
    });
```

I am assuming this is something to do with `z-index`? I have tried to add a high `z-index` to the icons but no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: btw, is there any reason why are not upgrading to v3? It has built-in social sharing module.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just needing to add my click event handlers into the `afterShow()` in fancybox:

```
afterShow: function() {
   // on click code goes in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind click events using some callback (`afterShow`, for example) or use event delegation (for example, `$('body').on('click', '.fb-icon-link', function() {});`), because these elements do not exist before starting fancyBox.